# Getting data from Google Sheets to BigQuery

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I need to pull data from a Google Sheet into BigQuery. So far I have created a Table in BQ using the CSV option and all of the data imported fine. But now I need to automatically update the BQ table with the data in the Google Sheet's tab. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

With BigQuery you can directly query your data from the Google Sheet by creating an external table from the console.

Given your data is properly formatted, you just have to "create table", from "Drive", provide your Google Sheet uri, fill-in some additional settings and that's it !

Any changes in the spreadsheet will be immediately accessible in BigQuery as well.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at BQ when they released and quickly dismissed it as it is free for a short period and then we have to pay. I have my own domain/website and it comes with MySQL, FTP, and so much more.

Anyway, I have many projects that go the opposite direction, pull the data down from the SQL DB to sheets, but which direction does not really matter.

Google sheets has Triggers, I have triggers set to launch at certain times, usually every day, you get to set up the trigger to fire off a function you specify.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder

You can also set triggers via scripts

```
/**
 * Creates time-driven triggers
 *
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder
 */
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every day at 04:00AM CT.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('csvDaily')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(4)
      .create();
}
```